# Using accessible taxicab rides as a medical deduction if labeled as a therapy

Tags: tax-law, medical

I once heard my tax accountant saying that taxi rides can only be used as a medical expense if they are for a medical appointment.

Let's assume a disabled person cannot drive a handicap vehicle, but they still need to get to work.  Suppose this person's home is outside the regulated boundary of the federally funded complimentary paratransit in the municipality in which they live.  In other words, they do not have any other form of transportation other than an accessible taxi service.  Their employer lets them work from home, but their health has gotten worse because of it, because they don't leave their home very often.  This person is also not eligible for Medical Assistance, Social Security Disability Income, nor any transportation services funded through these programs because their income is too high.  It's greater than 250% FPL (federal poverty level).  But this person depends on a wheelchair and cannot take other modes of transportation because they are unable to transfer.  These details might be irrelevant to the tax situation, but they are true nonetheless.

Suppose they get a script from their doctor saying that taxi rides to work (or anywhere) are a form of medical therapy to improve their health because they need to be around more people and not be isolated at home alone all the time.  Can those taxi rides be a medical deduction on their tax return?

Answer (score -2):

> Can those taxi rides be a medical deduction on their tax return?

Of course and when the IRS challenges the deductions a judge will decide if they are legitimate deductions or not.

Comment: Dale, I will call the IRS and ask them to confirm.  I've been keeping an eye on this answer, but do not know if it is true quite yet.  Two people downvoted and one person upvoted.  It's unfortunate that these folks are not commenting why they are voting.

Comment: @MacGyver, not having downvoted, I'll wager a guess anyhow: answers of the form "try it and see what a judge thinks" aren't well-tailored to virtually any question on the site.  The IRS publishes extensive guidance on medical deductions, and downvoters are likely trying to move an answer with little research effort to the bottom of the pile in keeping with the SE model.

Comment: They sure don't like short answers or process oriented answers like this on this site.  But I agree with the notion that you have the legal right to claim grey area scenarios in your reported return to your favor so +1.  Is there an ICD-9 code for "taxi therapy"?

Comment: Social Isolation = 2012 ICD-9-CM Diagnosis Code V62.4 : Social maladjustment. ICD-9-CM V62.4 is a billable medical code that can be used to indicate a diagnosis on a reimbursement claim, however, V62.4 should only be used for claims with a date of service on or before September 30, 2015.

Comment: The treatment for this ICD-9 code is medical therapy of getting taxi rides to town to get out of social isolation